# How to get max date among others ids for current id using BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I need to get max date for each row over other ids. Of course I can do this with `CROSS JOIN` and `JOIN` .
Like this

```
WITH t AS (
    SELECT 1 AS id, rep_date FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY('2021-09-01','2021-09-09', INTERVAL 1 DAY)) rep_date
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 2 AS id, rep_date FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY('2021-08-20','2021-09-03', INTERVAL 1 DAY)) rep_date
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 3 AS id, rep_date FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY('2021-08-25','2021-09-05', INTERVAL 1 DAY)) rep_date    
)
SELECT id, rep_date, MAX(rep_date) OVER (PARTITION BY id) max_date, max_date_over_others FROM t
JOIN (
   SELECT t.id, MAX(max_date) max_date_over_others FROM t 
   CROSS JOIN (
       SELECT id, MAX(rep_date) max_date FROM t
       GROUP BY 1
   ) t1
   WHERE t1.id <> t.id
   GROUP BY 1    
) USING (id)
```

But it's too wired for huge tables. So I'm looking for the some simpler way to do this. Any ideas?

Comment: You should add the `sql` flag as well, methinks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your version is good enough I think. But if you want to try other options  - consider below approach. It might looks more verbose from first look - but should be more optimal and cheaper to compare with your version with cross join

```
temp as (
  select id, 
    greatest(
      ifnull(max(max_date_for_id) over preceding_ids, '1970-01-01'), 
      ifnull(max(max_date_for_id) over following_ids, '1970-01-01')
    ) as max_date_for_rest_ids
  from (
    select id, max(rep_date) max_date_for_id
    from t
    group by id
  )
  window 
    preceding_ids as (order by id rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding),
    following_ids as (order by id rows between 1 following and unbounded following)
)
select *
from t 
join temp
using (id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your original table `data` just has columns `id` and `dt` - wouldn't this solve it? I'm using the fact that if an `id` has the max `dt` of everything, then it gets the second-highest over the other `id` values.

```sql
WITH max_dates AS
(
  SELECT
    id,
    MAX(dt) AS max_dt
  FROM
    data
  GROUP BY
    id
),

with_top1_value AS
(
  SELECT
    *,
    MAX(dt) OVER () AS max_overall_dt_1,
    MIN(dt) OVER () AS min_overall_dt
  FROM
    max_dates
),

with_top2_values AS
(
  SELECT
    *,
    MAX(CASE WHEN dt = max_overall_dt_1 THEN min_overall_dt ELSE dt END) AS max_overall_dt2
  FROM
    with_top1_value
),

SELECT
  *,
  CASE WHEN dt = max_overall_dt1 THEN max_overall_dt2 ELSE max_overall_dt1 END AS max_dt_of_others
FROM
  with_top2_values
```